# How do I aggregate/sort the results of one column based on data in another?

Tags: sql, group-by, count

I have a table displaying three columns, A, B, C. Column A has duplicate values. How do I sort the results based on column C?

For example:

```
A                   B                C
Amanda                            healthy
Amanda                            healthy
Brian                             healthy
Brian                               sick
Brian                             healthy
Colleen                            [null]
Colleen                             sick
Tyler                              healthy
Tyler                               [null]
Tyler                               fever
Daniel                              [null]
Daniel                              [null]
Daniel                              [null]
```

So that's just an example. I've left column B blank because it doesn't really matter here. What I'm trying to do is aggregate the duplicates in A based on the results in C. If all the results are null, then that should show me value 0. If the results are all healthy, or a mixture of healthy and null, then I want value 1. If there is any mention of being sick in the results, I want that to be value 2.

So for example, in the above, I want Amanda to give me value 1, Brian 2, Colleen 2, Tyler 2, Daniel 0. Any thoughts on how I may go about doing that? Thank you!

Comment: Pls share what you have tried, so that you could get a better solution

Comment: Please tag your RDBMS (which Db you are using: MySQL, MSSQL, etc).

Answer (score 0):

From your data and results, it looks like want `count(distinct)`:

```
select a, count(distinct c) cnt
from mytbale
group by a
```

From the description of your question, that's a bit different. You can use a `case` expression:

```
select 
    a,
    case 
        when max(case when c = 'sick'    then 1 else 0 end) = 1 then 2
        when max(case when c = 'healthy' then 1 else 0 end) = 1 then 1
        when count(c) = 0 then 0
    end as res
from mytable
group by a
```

Comment: I think the case needs to be reordered so the sick case comes **before** the healthy case because the requirement is that as soon as there is at least one sick, the result should be 2 and the first matching case wins.

Answer (score 0):

First step: register the incidences (yes/no = 1/0) of the possible outcomes in C per A:

```
SELECT a,BIT_XOR(CASE WHEN c IS NULL THEN 1 WHEN c="healthy" THEN 2 ELSE 4 END) FROM table GROUP BY a;
```

(here I've assumed that "sickness" and "fever" are to be treated similarly since you didn't specify what e.g. all "fever"'s should yield)

In that query the outputs are:

- 1 if all NULL (for c).
- 2 if all "healthy".
- 3 if all "healthy" (at least 1) or NULL (at least one)
- otherwise (1xxb) if there is at least one incidence of "sick"/"fever".

To adapt those outputs to your desirable values (0/1/1/2 for the respective cases) the query can be adapted to e.g.

```
SELECT a,If(bitmap=1,0,IF(bitmap&4,2,1)) FROM 
(SELECT a,BIT_XOR(CASE WHEN c IS NULL THEN 1 WHEN c="healthy" THEN 2 ELSE 4 END) bitmap FROM table GROUP BY a) tmp;
```

PS: if you have allergic reactions to this nested query (e.g. because the SQL server might not optimize it by itself), just rewrite it into a single query by repeating the inner expression, or simply translate the values of the original query at the receiving end.

Answer (score 0):

That script is for oracle, but the 'select' is SQL-92. Hope it will be useful for you.

```
create table anamnesis (
    a varchar(20),
    c varchar(20)
);

INSERT ALL
  INTO anamnesis (a, c) VALUES ('Amanda','healthy')
  INTO anamnesis (a, c) VALUES ('Amanda','healthy')
  INTO anamnesis (a, c) VALUES ('Brian','healthy')
  INTO anamnesis (a, c) VALUES ('Brian','sick')
  INTO anamnesis (a, c) VALUES ('Brian','healthy')
  INTO anamnesis (a, c) VALUES ('Colleen',null)
  INTO anamnesis (a, c) VALUES ('Colleen','sick')
  INTO anamnesis (a, c) VALUES ('Tyler','healthy')
  INTO anamnesis (a, c) VALUES ('Tyler',null)
  INTO anamnesis (a, c) VALUES ('Tyler','fever')
  INTO anamnesis (a, c) VALUES ('Daniel',null)
  INTO anamnesis (a, c) VALUES ('Daniel',null)
  INTO anamnesis (a, c) VALUES ('Daniel',null)
SELECT * FROM dual;

select t.a, (case when sick>0 then 2 else
                 case when healthy>0 then 1 else
                                          0
                 end
             end
            ) res
from
(select 
 t.a,
 sum(case when t.c is null then 1 else 0 end) nullable,
 sum(case when t.c='healthy' then 1 else 0 end) healthy,
 sum(case when coalesce(t.c,'-') not in ('-','healthy') then 1 else 0 end) sick
 from
 anamnesis t
 group by t.a) t;
```